# html/flask file to query postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

I'm hoping someone can help me, i am a complete beginner with Flask and Postgres.

Basically, I created a python file, that takes user input to query the existing postgres database, this works perfectly. However, now I want to create a flask web app to do the exact same.

Accept the user will input the name on the html text box, and once the user hits submit, it needs to query the Postgresql database and return the requested columns for that specific row, exactly like the `db_test.py` file does.

Below is my python file that works and give me the expected results, but when I tried to create the `app.py` file with the html file, I am not able to get it to work, and I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I don't know what.

This is the `db_connect.py` file that works - now I want to create the same results using flask and html.

```
# This is the db_test.py file which works as expected.
import psycopg2
# This section will try to create a Database Connection
try:
    db_connection = psycopg2.connect(
        host="localhost",
        database="my_db",
        user="postgres",
        password="password",
        port=5432
    )

# This section will test Database Connection and return an exception if the connection fails.
    print("Connected to server successfully")
except psycopg2.DatabaseError as Error:
    print(f"Connection failed to server {Error}")

# This is the user input for that will be used to query the database table.
name = input("What is the name? ").title()

# This is the cursor for querying the Database table for the name that the user input and prints out the title, name and email
cursor.execute(
    "SELECT id, name, email FROM details WHERE name = %s", (name,))
details = cursor.fetchall()
for d in details:
    print(d)

# This Cursor closes the database connection and an If Statement to check and confirm that the database connection is closed.
cursor.close()

# This closes the connection to the Database
if db_connection:
    db_connection.close()
    print("Disconnected from server")
```

This is the second part of the project, with flask and html, but I can't get it to work.

This is the `app.py` file:

```
import creds
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# initialising the app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = f"{creds.thisisasecret}"

# This is the Database URI
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f"postgresql://{creds.username}:{creds.password}@localhost:5432/{creds.database}"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATION'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Details(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'details'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(length=50))
    email = db.Column(db.String(length=30))



@app.route("/")
def show_details():
    return render_template("index.html", details=details.query.all())


app.run(debug=True, host="127.0.0.1", port=3000)
```

And this is the `index.html` file which also displays the text box with a submit button, but when i enter the name, nothing happens.

```
<body>
    <div>
        DB Search
    </div>
    <div>
        <form action="{{url_for('show_details')}}" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Name">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <hr/>
  
</body>
```

I have re-written the `app.py` and html file, I believe it's a lack of knowledge but all the research I'm doing online is not helping me fix this problem.

Basically when I type the name in the text box on the html page and click on submit, it should return the id, name and email on the html page.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to process form input with Flask, you'd define the form as below:

```html
<form method="POST">
```

then, to process it in Flask:

```py
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def show_details():
    if request.method == "POST":
        form_data = request.form
        name_entered_in_form = form_data["title"]  # Access form field by `name=` parameter
        new_details = ...  # populate data based on name entered
        return render_template("index.html", details=new_details)
    return render_template("index.html", details=details.query.all())
```

this code provides details about all fields in the database by default, and when a name is passed in and submitted, it passes in just those details to the exact same page. Note how the same app route ("/") is able to handle both types of requests - GET requests for displaying data and POST requests for handling submitted data.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to assist me, im still getting the same results. i can type the name in the input box on the html page, but once i click submit, nothing happens. i dont even get any errors haha